# SocketTimeoutException when using soap in android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, timeoutexception

I used this code in AsyncTask for sending string to my web service.

```
    public String postData()
    { 
        String strRet = ""; 
        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

            request.addProperty("val",dataField);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true; 
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); 
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            //Get the response
            SoapPrimitive  response = (SoapPrimitive ) envelope.getResponse(); 
            strRet = response.toString();
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) { 
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {  
        } catch (SoapFault e) { 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
        } 
        return strRet;
    }
```

my web service is asp.net(vb.net)
my asmx code is simple same this:

```
  <WebMethod()> _
Public Function Save(ByVal val As String) As String
    Return "success";
End Function
```

when my string is small it's ok and work fine, but when my string length is big(for example 3000 char), it not work and return this exception in **IOException**

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

how i can fix this problem?